WiFi AX not working on TPLink ax73
I bought TPLink ax73 and I can't connect to it with WiFi ax, unfortunately, I have only 1 device with AX card - laptop with Mediatek MT7921, which connects using Wifi AC. I tested this laptop with other AX routers, including cheaper TPLinks as ax53 and ax23 and they worked perfectly fine. Ax73 is updated to latest firmware.

How close is the router to the laptop? You could measure the strength of the router's signal using some app on the laptop or your smartphone.

I tested different distances, even close to router, signal is very high, even transfer rates are close to AC maximum with 2 antennas.

There have encountered here before unexplained cases where a card and a router refused to connect. Probably a question of software and router firmware, but it'll be hard to analyze. If the same wifi protocols are supported on both sides.

I think it's router's fault, I set it to AX only mode and laptop still connects with AC, and weirdly, smartphone without AX support can connect.

AX is downwards compatible with AC, but some AC devices may have a problem with making the initial connection to AX devices.

I sorted it out, changing 5Ghz channel to any other option fixed it.

A pity you had to opt to a slower network, but better document your fix in an answer, and come back later to mark it as accepted, for future visitors.
